# Detect if user Idle on windows universal app

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10, idle-processing

I'm developing a class library for windows 10 universal apps (mobile and desktop device families only). I need to invoke an event if the user has been idle(no touch, mouse move, key press etc) for x number of seconds. [This method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction()) can be used to solves this problem on android. But I couldn't find a solution on windows UWP.

Is there an API available in UWP to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, Check this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41194976/776075

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can detect global input with various events on the app's CoreWindow:

Touch and mouse input with CoreWindow.PointerPressed, PointerMoved, and PointerReleased.

Keyboard input: KeyUp and KeyDown (the soft keys) and CharacterReceived (for characters generated via chords & text suggestions)

Use these to detect the user is active and idle out if it goes too long without any of these events.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is really old question, but I think you can now get to same result with [RegisterBackgroundTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/register-a-background-task)

Just set:

`new TimeTrigger(15, false) //For time trigger`

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-a-background-task-on-a-timer-)

`new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.UserNotPresent)) //And so you want to know so user is not present`

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemconditiontype?view=winrt-20348)

Example usage in App.xaml.cs:

```cs
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
builder.Name = "Is user Idle";
builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(2, false)); //two mins
builder.AddCondition(new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.UserNotPresent));
// Do not set builder.TaskEntryPoint for in-process background tasks
// Here we register the task and work will start based on the time trigger.
BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
task.Completed += (sender, args) =>
{
    //Handle user not present (Idle) here.
};
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Added solution example.

Comment: The `TimeTrigger` Class has a minimum value which is `15` minutes. You could not set a time interval that less than `15` minutes to the `TimeTrigger`. This is mentioned here: `TimeTrigger.FreshnessTime Property`