# Detect if user Idle on computer (vs in a windows universal app)

Tags: windows-store-apps, idle-processing

The solution given here :
[Detect if user Idle on windows universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114031/detect-if-user-idle-on-windows-universal-app/34774058#34774058)
allows to detect the user idle inside the app. When the user is active elsewhere, the app considers only the activity in the app.
So, how to detect a full user idle on the computer in a universal app?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the system trigger "UserAway" described here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtriggertype.aspx

You could use it to fire a background task - depending on your specific scenario this might help you.

Comment: But it seems that "UserAway" triggers the lock screen. I don't want to use this event because my app requires to be active permanently (Bluetooth connection, synthethic voice, ..).Depending on the user choice, the idle will be used to turn off the screen only, not to lock.